# How to handle redirections in nginx ingress for a Kubernetes cluster which has microservices swagger hosted in it?

Tags: kubernetes, swagger, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am working on a new Kubernetes cluster setup. This setup will have about 25 microservices hosted in 25 different pods. These will be exposed via 25 different NodePort services. To access them from outside, I'm trying to integrate **nginx ingress with a NLB**(Note: all of this setup is hosted in AWS EKS)
Now, the microservices uses swagger which means there is redirection in the URL.

> For e.g:  https://example.com/customerservice ->
> https://example.com/swagger/index.html (customerservice svc->pod)
> https://example.com/orderservice ->
> https://example.com/swagger/index.html (orderservice svc->pod)

So on and so forth for the rest of the 23 services

The services work for the info or healthpoint if I enter the whole URL like below:

> https://example.com/orderservice/v3/info
>
> https://example.com/customerservice/v3/healthcheck

The above endpoints works fine if I enter the whole URL manually. However, the users will expect to enter only https://example.com/customerservice, and it should redirect to the respective swagger page like this https://example.com/swagger/index.html

Below is my ingress YAML file, which is working for whole URLs like a v3/info or healthcheck, but not doing the redirection properly.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
  labels:
    app: trial-ingress
  name: trial-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: customerservice-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /customerservice(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: orderservice-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /orderservice(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
```

If I use the above ingress and try to load **https://example.com/customerservice** then it redirects me to **https://example.com/swagger/** which means it is trying to redirect in the correct direction but only takes in **one argument/word (swagger)** and removes rest of the string which then gives a 404 error

**Expected Result:** When user tries to load **https://example.com/customerservice** it should redirect to **https://example.com/swagger/index.html** page of the `customerservice` pod and similarly for all other services

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following YAML file if it helps:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-demo
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$3
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-prefix: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /()()(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: customerservice-svc
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /orderservice(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: orderservice-svc
            port:
              number: 80
```

You can also read related threads on this [link](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/6838#issuecomment-1023974340).

Answer (score -1):

To handle redirections in nginx ingress for a Kubernetes cluster hosting microservices with Swagger, you need to set up your [ingress rules](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#ingress-rules) to properly redirect requests to the appropriate Swagger documentation URL.

That means updating the [`rewrite-target` annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#rewrite) to redirect to the swagger `index.html`.
And then add custom logic using more advanced nginx configurations, done with the [`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet` annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#configuration-snippet), which adds custom configurations to the Location configuration block (as [mentioned here](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/en/ack/ack-managed-and-ack-dedicated/user-guide/advanced-nginx-ingress-configurations#title-kvh-0h5-vll)).

Your Ingress YAML would be:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /swagger/index.html
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      rewrite ^(/customerservice)$ $1/ redirect;
      rewrite ^(/orderservice)$ $1/ redirect;
      # Add similar rewrite rules for other services
  labels:
    app: trial-ingress
  name: trial-ingress
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: customerservice-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /customerservice(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: orderservice-svc
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /orderservice(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
      # Add paths for other services
```

That would rewrite requests from `https://example.com/customerservice` to `https://example.com/customerservice/swagger/index.html` (specific to the customer service), and similarly for other services.

You would get:

```
 ┌─────────────┐       ┌─────────────┐       ┌─────────────────────┐
 │             │       │             │       │                     │
 │    User     │──────►│     NLB     │──────►│  NGINX Ingress      │
 │             │       │             │       │                     │
 └─────────────┘       └─────────────┘       └─────────────────────┘
                                                           │
                                                           │
                                                           ▼
 ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
 │                               Microservices in Pods               │
 │                                                                   │
 │   /customerservice ────────────► (Customer Service Pod Swagger)   │
 │                                                                   │
 │   /orderservice    ────────────► (Order Service Pod Swagger)      │
 │                                                                   │
 │                                  (Other Services)                 │
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

(To be tested in a staging environment first, before deploying it to production!)